# Is identity generator in Hibernate a singleton?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

How Hibernate deals with identity generators? Generator class looks like a singleton with it's synchronized *generate* method with no static fields. Is generator instance created for each session, is it JVM level singleton, or it's handled in totally different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate has many identifier generators and [IDENTITY, SEQUENCE and TABLE](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) are using the database for generating a new identifier value. The synchronization happens in the database using locks (soft-locks for IDENTITY and SEQUENCE and hard locks for TABLE).

The generators are stored in the `SessionFactory` so they are shared by all `Sessions`.